# find any non asci characters in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to fail if a string contains any non-ascii characters:

This works when there is only 1 non-ascii char:

```
/[\x20-\x7E\s]/.test('☃')
```

But fails when it is part of a string

```
/[\x20-\x7E\s]/.test('sus☃')
```

Comment: There *has* to be a dupetarget for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a negated character class, so *any* character *outside* the range matches:

```
!/[^\x20-\x7E\s]/.test('sus☃')
```

Alternately, use anchors and a quantifier:

```
/^[\x20-\x7E\s]+$/.test('sus☃')
```

That's using `+` (requires one character). Yo ucould use `*` instead (zero or more).

Comment: *(If you don't see `!` on the first example, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Should not work with `\s`

Comment: @Maxim: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that, unless you mean that `\s` will match various non-ASCII whitespace, such as `\u00A0`? I figured the OP had it there on purpose, so I left it, but...